# No Bootstrap 4, existe alguma maneira do menu colapsado ser exibido vindo da direita da tela e não da parte superior dela?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, menu

o código html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Testando o Botstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <header>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand mb-0">Curso</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-mw">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu-mw">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">A Empresa</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a href="" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Produtos</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">SOLIDWORKS</a>
                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">SOLIDWORKS Simulation</a>
                                <a href="" class="dropdown-item">SOLIDWORKS Composer</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
         
    </header>
    </main>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara isso existem em uma documentação nos próprios exemplos do Bootstrap. Eles chamam esse tipo de menu de **`offcanvas menu`** vc pode consultar direto no link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/offcanvas

Veja que eles mesmo falam que é um modelo classificado como experimental...!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Agora vamos ao  código**

Aqui está o exemplo simplificado com o código retirado diretamente da documentação , porém veja, que mesmo sendo algo original do Bootstrap foi preciso incluir algum CSS customizado e JS, mas nada de mais, não deve dar 50 linhas de código isso.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />



<style>
  .bd-placeholder-img {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    text-anchor: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
      font-size: 3.5rem;
    }
  }

  html,
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* Prevent scroll on narrow devices */
  }

  body {
    padding-top: 56px;
  }

  @media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .offcanvas-collapse {
      position: fixed;
      top: 56px;
      /* Height of navbar */
      bottom: 0;
      left: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding-right: 1rem;
      padding-left: 1rem;
      overflow-y: auto;
      visibility: hidden;
      background-color: #343a40;
      transition: visibility .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
      transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, visibility .3s ease-in-out;
      transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, visibility .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
    }

    .offcanvas-collapse.open {
      visibility: visible;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
  }

  .nav-scroller {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 2.75rem;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }

  .nav-scroller .nav {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-top: -1px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }

  .nav-underline .nav-link {
    padding-top: .75rem;
    padding-bottom: .75rem;
    font-size: .875rem;
    color: #6c757d;
  }

  .nav-underline .nav-link:hover {
    color: #007bff;
  }

  .nav-underline .active {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #343a40;
  }

  .text-white-50 {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  }

  .bg-purple {
    background-color: #6f42c1;
  }

  .lh-100 {
    line-height: 1;
  }

  .lh-125 {
    line-height: 1.25;
  }

  .lh-150 {
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body class="bg-light">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto mr-lg-0" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" data-toggle="offcanvas">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Switch account</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <main role="main" class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum ipsam itaque accusamus, consequuntur dolorem optio expedita labore perferendis, sint sed aliquam modi a repudiandae nam consectetur praesentium perspiciatis. Quibusdam, qui!
  </main>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      'use strict'

      $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').on('click', function() {
        $('.offcanvas-collapse').toggleClass('open')
      })
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**OBS:** Aqui tem uma lista completa de todos os **templates oficiais** do Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/ todos Free!